# Regular expression to remove 'item' from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I'm trying to rewrite URL's from:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/7730-coworking-aproveite-j%C3%A1-todas-as-vantagens-desta-nova-forma-de-trabalhar.html
```

To:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/7730-coworking-aproveite-j%C3%A1-todas-as-vantagens-desta-nova-forma-de-trabalhar.html
```

This is what I'm trying in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+/item/(.+)$ /item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it seems I'm doing it wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URI starts with `item` so `.+/` won't match. Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^item/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```